# PostGIS returning a field one level higher in the Json

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I have the following SQL on a PostGIS Database ($properties contains a list of fields, including osm_id)

```
        SELECT row_to_json(fc)
            FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
            FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type,

            ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Intersection(lg.way, bbox.geom))::json As geometry, 
                    (
                       SELECT row_to_json(t) 
                         FROM 
                         (
                              SELECT $properties
                         ) t
                    )
             As properties
          FROM 
              planet_osm_polygon As lg, 
                ( 
                    SELECT ST_Transform ( ST_SetSRID(ST_MakeBox2d( ST_MakePoint( $topLon,$topLat) , ST_MakePoint( $botLon , $botLat) ), $srid) , 900913 ) as geom
                ) as bbox 

                WHERE "building" is NOT NULL AND ST_Intersects(lg.way, bbox.geom)
                    ) As f 
                ) fc;
```

that returns GeoJson in this format

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
            ],
     "properties": {
        "osm_id": 278325855,
        "height": "80.4"
    }
},
```

I need to return it in THIS format, note the extra `id` field at the `properties` and `geometry` level. The value to be returned is the same as the `osm_id` in the properties.

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": 3698396,
    "properties": {
        "height": 54
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": 
            [
            ]
        ]
    }
},
```

How can I do this in a Query, or would it be more efficient to parse the Json and add it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, sorry had to replace your variables with real values so I could test, but should be easy enough for you to replace back with what you had.  Also note I replace your ST_MakeBox2D/ST_SetSRID with ST_MakeEnvelope which is shorter and generally more accurate.

```
WITH c AS (SELECT -88.505 As topLon, 41.8046 As topLat, -88.405 As botLon, 41.906 As botLat, 4326 As srid)  ,
bbox AS (SELECT ST_Transform ( ST_MakeEnvelope( topLon, topLat , botLon , botLat , srid) , 900913 ) As geom
    FROM c )
  SELECT row_to_json(fc)
        FROM ( SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features
        FROM (SELECT 'Feature' As type, osm_id As id,

            (
                   SELECT row_to_json(t) 
                     FROM 
                     (
                          SELECT  tags->'height' As height
                     ) t
                )
         As properties,
        ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Intersection(lg.way, bbox.geom))::json As geometry 

      FROM 
          planet_osm_polygon As lg, 
            bbox

            WHERE building is NOT NULL AND ST_Intersects(lg.way, bbox.geom)
                ) As f 
            ) fc;
```

Comment: Excellent, well done, nothing close to what I was doing .. Thanks for the ST_MakeEnvelope tip as well ..